# Issue while saving mongoDB document size more than 16 MB

Tags: mongodb

We are using MongoDB 3.0.5 , We have collection of Blog

```
Blogs{
title:"",
dateCreated:"",
userId:"",
body:"",
likes:[{userId:"",dateCreated:""}] //Array List of those person who likes the blog
comments:[{userId:"",dateCreated:"",comment:""}] //Array list of comments
shares :[{userID:"",dateCreated:""}]
}
```

Right now we have around 1000 likes and around 50 comments , our document size is increasing day by day and I think after some time it may be more than 16 MB

So now we think to break our Documents into -:
1) Blogs
2) Likes
3) Comments 
4) Shares

```
Blogs { 
    title:"",
    dateCreated:"",
    userId:"",
    body:""
}
Comments {
    userId:"",
    dateCreated:"",
    comment:""
    blogid:""
} 
Shares {
        userId:"",
        dateCreated:"",
        blogid:""
    } 
Likes {
        userId:"",
        dateCreated:"",
        blogid:""
    }
```

This schema we are thinking to create but it looks there is performance issue in it because for 1 Blogs show we need to calculate total likes , total shares , and total comments .

IS there any better option than this ?

Comment: Before breaking your documents into subdocuments remember one thing MongoDB doesn’t support joins as they do not scale horizontally.

Comment: Yeah I know that mongoDB does not support joins , And that is why I says there is performance issue . For showing a Blog we need to execute 4 query i.e. count for likes,shares,comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could spare the calculations on view, if you update a field every time you write. Assuming viewing is done more often then writing this should not be a big problem. Hence you could use the following schema:

```
Blog {
  title:"",
  dateCreated:"",
  userId:"",
  body:""
  shares: Int
  likes: Int
}
```

Now every time a user clicks the Like button you can update the field that counts the likes, and also save for each user the ID of the blog he liked.

```
User {
   name:
   registration_date:
   likes: [ blogid1, blogid2, blogid3 ... ]
   shares: [ blogid7, blogid18, blogid39 ... ]
}
```

So a click event, write to two documents, but viewing is much simpler now.

#### update

OK, so this is how I would go about it, but there is really no "correct way" it depends a lot about what you are trying to achieve with your blog.

I assume most blog post would not have more then a few dozens of comments, hence I would do choose the following model for blog:

```
Blog {
  title:"",
  dateCreated:"",
  userId:"",
  body:""
  shares: Int
  likes: Int
  comments: [ { user: "foo", date: 2015-07-09, body: "great post"},  { user: "bar", date: 2015-07-10, body: "awesome post"}]
   commentrecords: []
}
```

For those extreme cases where you have a blog post record with more than a 100 comments you can do this:

```
PostComments {
_id : ObjectID(abce)
comments: [ { user: "foo", date: 2015-07-09, body: "great post"},  { user: "bar", date: 2015-07-10, body: "awesome post"}]

}

PostComments {
_id : ObjectID(1234)
comments: [ { user: "Baz", date: 2015-07-09, body: "great post"},  { user: "tom", date: 2015-07-10, body: "awesome post"}]
}

Blog {
  title:"Very popular post",
  dateCreated:"",
  userId:"",
  body:""
  shares: Int
  likes: Int
  comments: []
  comment_records: [ObjectID(1234), ObjectID(abce)]
}
```

Following this path, your application code has to check which of fields `comments` or `comment_records` exists and act accordingly. That means for most of the time you will need just 1 fetch to load a blog post, and for some rare cases you will two or more rounds (depending on the amount of comments). If you need more than two round, you might not want to rload them all at one, because maybe most users read the latest comments anyway, so you build your application in such way that the user click on `previous comments` (in fact it has a name: pagination) to load more comments.

Regarding `Likes` and `Shares`

You created a collection of likes and shares, such that if you want to know all the user likes and share, you have to traverse the collection and find all of them. 
If you track users activity it makes sense to keep this information close to the user. Hence, I would put this information inside the user record:

```
User:
  {name : "foo"
   password: '******',
   email: 'foo@example.org', 
   likes: [{_id: objectid(1), date: 2013-01-01} , {_id: objectid(2), date: 2013-01-02},  {_id: objectid(3), date: 2013-01-01}]
   shares: [{_id: objectid(1), date: 2013-01-01} , {_id: objectid(2), date: 2013-01-02},  {_id: objectid(3), date: 2013-01-01}]
    }
```

If your user record have too many likes and share, you can take the same approach as with comments, and reap them out and the make a "relation" over ids.

```
User:
  {name : "foo"
   password: '******',
   email: 'foo@example.org', 
   like_records: [objectid(abfe21h), objected(eeebg001) ]
   share_records: [objectid(ffe11h), ]
    }

like_record {
       _id : objectid(abfe21h)
       likes: [{_id: objectid(1), date: 2013-01-01} , {_id: objectid(2), date: 2013-01-02},  {_id: objectid(3), date: 2013-01-01}]
       }   

share_record {
       _id : objectid(ffe11h) 
       shares: [{_id: objectid(1), date: 2013-01-01} , {_id: objectid(2),    date: 2013-01-02},  {_id: objectid(3), date: 2013-01-01}]
       }
```

Comment: Yeah now for write we execute 2 Query and for view only 1 query is executed And what about comments ?

Comment: @abhaygarg12493, see my update answer. I hope it gives you enough details.

Comment: Thanks a lot you explain everything but for fetching who shares the blogs and who likes the blogs I have to fetch from all users in share_records and that is a List . Will this cause a issue who likes or shares a particular Blog for around 10,000 users ? By $IN it is easily achievable I am just worrying related to performance issue

Comment: This didn't work I create likes object contains date and blogID and after inserting 100000 likes object size of BSON oject becomes more than 16 MB . So our point of view if user continues our website for 10 years then  it beaks

Comment: You can use multiple like_records for each record, so your are not limited. I modified the record structure to show this. Plus, don't just save everything just because you can. collecting `likes` data should be done with a purpose. Maybe after 3 years you can identify patterns, user preferences, such the older likes can be removed? May be in 10 years you will need another schema?

Comment: No we can not remove likes or anything , this is also important for any Blog who likes (userInfo) this post . So after sometimes we can do Recommendation to another users of Same Blogs like

Answer (score -2):

You can use [GridFS API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) in mongodb to store your document with size limit greater than 16 MB. Also read [when should i use GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-when-to-use-gridfs)